# Add extra fields for each menu item

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am making a theme. There I want to add extra fields for each menu items ( *Appearance > Menus* and i.e). In the picture below I want to add some extra form fields ( like radio button, textarea and etc. ) under the field "Description":

[image: menu item wordpress]

Is there any way or tutorial about how can I do this?

Answer (score 12):

I was looking for the same thing.
I found these, all of which work differently.

**https://gist.github.com/kucrut/3804376**
simple to use and straightforward if you plan to build an elaborate class 
(note: with mods this could be used for checkboxes, radio, color pickers, ect)

**https://wordpress.org/plugins/sweet-custom-menu/**
This worked well, very simple, adds a txt field. 
(note: it overrides the whole wordpress_walker class)

**http://www.johnmorrisonline.com/how-to-add-a-fully-functional-custom-meta-box-to-wordpress-navigation-menus/**
This is very different, it adds an entire mettabox type to the admin menu panel on the LEFT. I elected to use this as I was building my own version of a "mega menu" and wanted to add widgets. With enough work on this item and the one above anything is possible.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want an extra field for, but sometimes this kind of problem can be resolved by looking at an alternative approach: Add in a [shortcode in your menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-in-menus/), giving you the programmatic flexibility to customise your menu item output beyond what is offered by WP.